# Difference between '' and "" in Python

Tags: python

What is the difference between apostrophes and quotation marks in Python?

So far I've only been able to find one difference

```
print "'"

print '"'

print '''

print """
```

The first print statement will output **'** while the second **"**. However the third statement starts a comment block.

Any other differences I should be aware of?

Comment: Which tutorial are you using?  This is pretty fully explained in most of them.  Which one did you find that doesn't explain this?

Comment: "Close as duplicate" needs to have its close cousin, "answered in the documentation".  SO shouldn't become a mirror for every piece of information that's already well-documented in the proper place.

Comment: @Glenn: Except making SO be *the* place to go was the founders' intention...

Comment: @Roger: To duplicate every API reference, language spec, manpage, RFC, ANSI, IEEE and ISO chapter?  That would render the site useless, burying the useful information under a landfill of crap and (further) encouraging people to ask-before-searching.  I sure hope that's not the intention.

Comment: @Glenn: Have you followed the "no question is too basic" / "how do I move the turtle in logo?" debate, both here and on SO.meta?  I'm not saying it is a *good policy* (I'm mostly undecided), only that it *is* the policy — and hence why there isn't a "RTFM" or "get a book" close reason.

Comment: @Roger: There are a lot of poor "policies" on this site.  Given how many of them there are (vote locks, minimum comment length, *maximum* comment length, stealth answer editing), and the tone on meta when people dare to explain issues, I've long since decided to steer clear.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`print 'Hello'` and `print "Hello"` are the same and what you use is your personal preference. `"""` and `'''` are for multiline strings.

```
>>> print """First
Second
Third"""

First
Second
Third
```

Answer (score 8):

> Python has a facility multiline string that starts with triple quotes.

They are also commonly used for docstrings.

- http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/

An example of multiline string:

```
>>> x = """ wdd2ed
... 2wdqd
... d
... dd
... d
... """
>>> 
>>> print x
 wdd2ed
2wdqd
d
dd
d

>>>
```

String literals can be enclosed in matching single quotes (') or double quotes (").
So "string" and 'string' are same.

The following provides all the details: http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Answer (score 5):

Triple-quotes aren't for comments, they are the syntax for multi-line strings.  They are often used for docstrings, which serve a similar role as block comments in other languages.  But multi-line strings can be used as data just as the other string syntaxes can.

Answer (score 4):

'...' strings and "..." are identical except that you don't need to escape `'` inside a `"` string, nor vice versa.

Triple quotes start a multi-line string.  These are often used for [docstrings](http://diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/documenting_functions.html), which is probably where you got the idea that they're comments.

Answer (score 3):

`'` and `"` can be used interchangably to start and end a string (be sure to close with the same one you opened with).  It's provided as a convenience so you don't need to escape quote in most cases.

For example, if you wanted the string `say "hello"` in languages that don't provide the alternative option, you would need to escape it with something like `"say \"hello\""` which is somewhat ugly compared to `'say "hello"'`

Likewise if you could only use `'` (not sure of any language that does this) then a string to say `bill's pony` would be `'bill\'s pony'` instead of `"bill's pony"`.

Answer (score 1):

Note: in PHP string quoted by single-quotes ' don't interpret escapes like '\n' '\r' etc. In python you can use 'r' modifier. So, `str=r'some \n string containing "\n" inside'`
 - is RAW string and it does not contain newline characters.